# How to set up webbrowser to text browser

Tags: c#, browser

My previous question is here ["how can i read content generated via ajax using webclient"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368350/how-can-i-read-content-generated-via-ajax-using-webclient)

I need to only download html text content, i don't need any picture and other streaming data.

How to set up System.Windows.Forms.Webbrowser to text browser?

is it possible?

regard

ebattulga

Comment: Try using System.Net.WebClient.

Comment: look my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368350/how-can-i-read-content-generated-via-ajax-using-webclient

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requires a javascript engine to run it - using a simple WebRequest etc. will ontly return the HTML and the Javascript definition, then functions won't actually run.